# Promethus/Grafana Histogram_quantile never shows data from le="+inf" bucket

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to understand how many requests are served in over 10s for a service.  To get a sense of the latency distribution overall, I look at the Heatmap in Grafana for this query.

```
(sum by (le) (rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter="source", destination_app="my-server",response_code!~"(5..|429)"}[5m])))
```

This shows that I have le buckets that go up to 10000ms (10s) and a number of requests that fall into the +Inf bucket.  This is confirmed by the service owner, who states that there are some requests that we know will take 10+ seconds.  Now we want to find out what percentile those fall into. So I took a look at the histogram_quantile data using this query, starting with 99th percentile to see what lands there.

```
histogram_quantile(0.99,(sum by (le) (rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter="source",destination_app="my-server",response_code!~"(5..|429)"}[5m]))))
```

The weird thing is that I don't see *any* requests over 10 seconds in the 99th percentile.  If I change the percentile to 1 (100%) I see a flat line at 10s, with nothing over the top le bucket.  Can someone help me understand why I don't see any data for requests in the +inf bucket with histogram_percentile?

I would expect histogram_percentile 100% to show me all data including the +inf bucket.